# C# DataGridView capturing deleted row

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net, datagridview

**1.**

I am using a DataGridView, which is bound to a dataset. 
There is a bindingNavigator as well.

when a user deletes a row by clicking "bindingNavigatorDeleteItem" button, I am trying to get the row being deleted.

```
private void bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
        int crow = gridEventType.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

but it returns the newly selected row AFTER deletion of a selected row. 
so, If I have two rows
0
1
2
and I delete 2

crow is 1, not 2.

Am I missing something here?

**2. How do I know whether certain rows are modified in datagridview?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`.

```
private void bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(object sender, 
                                                  DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{
   int cRow =  gridEventType.Rows[e.RowIndex];

   //delete row from persisted storage

   //rebind data to persisted storage or remove row directly:
   gridEventType.Rows.RemoveAt(cRow);
}
```

For your second point, there's a [CellValueChangedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx).

```
    private void bindingNavigatorModifiedCell_CellValueChanged(object sender, 
                                                   DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         //updated row
         int cRow = e.RowIndex;
    }
```

Comment: I am unable to add an event handler which take DatagridViewCellEventArgs for bindingNavigatorDeleteItem

also, bindingNavigator does not have such CellValueChanged Event. I think this can work if I use it for DataGridView like : 

public void DataGridView_CellValueChanged(...)

Answer (score 3):

Use the datagridview.UserDeletingRow event to get the deleted row object.

Comment: Really, you should've added this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

For my Question #1.

- change "DeleteItem" property of BindingNavigator to (none)
- create an eventhandler of "DeleteItem_Clicked"
- get current row number by

  int cRow = gridEventType.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
- delete the current item from bindingsource

  BindingNavigator.BindingSource.RemoveCurrent();

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `UserDeletingRow` as an event handler for deleting a row, and inside this method you can get the row index and as below:

```
 private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        int tmpId = (int) e.Row.Index;
    }
```